# ReactiveMongo: How to use projection

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I'm trying to filter out the `password` field when querying a document from MongoDB with ReactiveMongo:

```
val projection = Json.obj("password" -> 0)

def find(selector: JsValue, projection: Option[JsValue]) = {
  val query = collection.genericQueryBuilder.query(selector)
  projection.map(query.projection(_))
  query.cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](perPage).transform(
    success => success,
    failure => failure match {
      case e: LastError => DaoException(e.message, Some(DATABASE_ERROR))
    }
  )
}
```

The code above has no effect... I also get the `password` field. If I try the following from the mongo client, then it works and `password` is not returned:

```
db.users.find( { username: 'j3d' }, { password:0} )
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
def find(selector: JsValue, projection: Option[JsValue]) = {
  var query = collection.genericQueryBuilder.query(selector)
  projection.map(query = query.projection(_))

  query.cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](perPage).transform(
    success => success,
    failure => failure match {
      case e: LastError => DaoException(e.message, Some(DATABASE_ERROR))
    }
  )
}
```

or alternatively:

```
def find(selector: JsValue, projection: Option[JsValue]) = {
  val query = collection.genericQueryBuilder
    .query(selector)
    .projection(projection.getOrElse(Json.obj())

  query.cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](perPage).transform(
    success => success,
    failure => failure match {
      case e: LastError => DaoException(e.message, Some(DATABASE_ERROR))
    }
  )
}
```

I hope that helps.